# error C2065 and IntelliSense

Tags: c++, intellisense

im programming on c++ and i have this errors for that code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ int x;
    printf("%d","Please enter a number\n");
    scanf(%d,&x);
    printf("%d","You entered 56\n");

}
```

This is the errors:
Error   1   error C2065: 'd' : undeclared identifier        9   1   ניסיון1

```
2   IntelliSense: expected an expression    9   8
```

Thanks, Peleg

Comment: This looks more C than C++

Comment: `printf("%d","You entered 56\n");` is not right either. You need `printf("You entered %d\n", x);`.

Comment: Neither is `printf("%d","Please enter a number\n");` you need `printf("Please enter a number\n");`. You might of seen lots of examples using %d but that doesn't mean you have to put %d in front of everything. Reread your books and try to understand what %d means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an 'undeclared identifier' error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197030/what-is-an-undeclared-identifier-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `scanf` should be a null-terminated string:

```
scanf("%d",&x);
```

Just as you have done with `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf(%d,&x);  
------^^----
```

Should be `scanf("%d",&x);`

Answer (score 0):

As the others already stated, scanf requires a format *string*, so you must write

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

Also your usage of printf will not produce the results you want. The first string passed to printf is the output format string. `"%d"` means that the next argument is an integer. Your next argument is the address of a string. What you really wanted to write is one of These three lines:

```
printf("%s", "Please enter a number\n");
printf("Please enter a number\n");
puts("Please enter a number");
```

The last line is best in your case. The second line is fine, too, but only because the string does not contain formatting characters like `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first argument of your `scanf(%d,&x);` statement. This argument should be a null terminated string. Your code is rewritten below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    int x;
    printf("Please enter a number %d\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("You entered %d\n", x);

}
```

Comment: I didn't actually understood what you mean "argument" and what is it null terminated string (I know what is string but not that kind".      Also, now i have another error:                                         Error 1 error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.  10 1